# Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster

Tags: asp.net

I've read countless posts on this topic, and tried several solutions but I'm still seeing this error.  I'm running iis6, .NET 2.0 on a single server.  When clicking a link on my form, and new page is opened that allows the user to enter a bunch of data (it's an order form).  When clicking save, I see this error:

"Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster."

I've verified that the page has finished loading before clicking the save button.

I've tried:

- adding enableViewStateMac="false" to the Page directive
- adding this to the web.config `<machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps"
                                 decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps"
                                 validation="SHA1"/>`
- adding viewStateEncryptionMode="Never"in the page tag in the web.config
- adding enableEventValidation="false" in the page tag in the web.config (which I'm not sure I should do)
- adding renderAllHiddenFieldsAtTopOfForm="false" in the page tag in the web.config

And I've checked for coding errors, but everything is working fine locally.  Does anyone have another suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: I just noticed something very interesting about this.  On the dev server, clicking save posts back to my local machine... very weird, I've never seen that.  Ex: click save on "http://DevServer/page.aspx" I see the error but the url in the browser is "http://localmachine/page.aspx."  How that happens, I don't know, but it explains the postback/validation error.

Comment: OK, I feel like an idiot.  I had hard coded my local machine name in the <base> tag during development (I was in a hurry).  I found some code to dynamically add a base tag to the page, and now everything is working fine...